# Find the tightest upper bound for a creation of an array (among few options)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, computer-science

Let `A`, an array of numbers. We need to create an array `B` such that `B[i] = min(A[i],...,A[i+sqrt(n)]`.

Why is the **tightest** upper bound for the creation of `B` is `O(nlogn)`?

I was actually given a list of options:

- `O(sqrt(n)*logn)`
- `O(n/logn)`
- `O(n*logn)`
- `O(nlog(n)^2)`
- `O(n*sqrt(n))`
- `O(n^2)`

Comment: Hmm.. Let me edit the question please

Comment: Can a upper bound be tight on itself? Iirc a tight bound is the combination (Theta) of the lower and upper bound

Comment: @daZza, I've edited the question which requests the tightest among the few options was given.

Comment: Your edit changes the question. It seems to be the author of the question means: `Which is the tightiest bound among the following: ....` (and not claiming that the problem cannot be solved better than the chosen answer), and since it can be done in `O(nlogn)`, and definetly cannot be done sub-linear, there is no other bound **on the list** which is tightier (and correct)

Comment: Thank you @amit, so basically I need to find an algorithm which works in `O(nlogn)` but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: To spell it out, the bound that amit and I were looking for is not on that list. Time to talk to your course staff.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, according to @amit, `O(nlogn)` is the answer if I had found such an algorithm. Isn't it right?

Comment: @AlonAlon O(nlogn) can be achieved with a sliding window and a binary tree of size sqrt(n) that you add and remove element from at each iteration. Complexity will be `O(n*log(sqrt(n)) = O(n*1/2*log(n)) = O(nlogn)`. All "lower" bounds are sublinear and thus impossible.

Comment: Oh I see. That's a wonderful solution. Thank you @amit

Comment: @AlonAlon Let me put it this way: Ω(n log n) is not a provable lower bound in the models usually considered for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `O(nlogn)`, since it is the lowest yet not sublinear option.

It can be done in `O(nlogn)` by maintaining a sorted DS (self balancing BST for example) of size `sqrt(n)`, and iteratively remove and add elements to it (while running a sliding window on the array). 

Each iteration is done in `O(log(sqrt(n)) = O(1/2*log(n)) = O(logn)`, and there are `O(n)` iterations, so total of `O(nlogn)`.

This disqualifies all "higher" alternatives, and all "lower" alternatives are sub-linear, and you cannot create the array in sublinear time.

Comment: "O(nlogn), since it is the lowest yet not sublinear option" - you know that's not a proof, don't you? of course there are other growth complexities in between.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I didn't claim it is the tightiest bound of this problem, I claimed it is the tightiest bound among the given possibilities - and the reason is, all lower alternatives are sublinear.